# How to get activities from trello board

Tags: api, trello

I have built a site that pulls the comments from Trello to show it on my site using this code:

```
    var resource = "cards/" + card.id + "/actions";
    Trello.get(resource, function(comments) {
            if(!$.isEmptyObject(comments)){
                    var commentStr="<div class='comments_c'>";
                    $.each(comments, function(c, cda){
                            //console.log(cda.data.text);
                            commentStr += "<p>"+cda.data.text+"</p>";
                            //addComments(cda.data.text);
                    });

                    commentStr += "</div>";
            }
            console.log(commentStr);
```

Now it works fine to pull the comments but it doesn't show the activity like "Sarah Hastings added this card to ". The api documentation doesn't talk about it and I am at a dead-end. We need it for reporting and looking for a way to get the activities (copied, moved, added) from Trello to our site. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `cards/[idCard]/actions` endpoint returns actions filtered to `commentCard,updateCard:idList`. If you want to get actions of additional types from that endpoint you will want to include the `filter` parameter with the list of action types that you want returned. You can see the full list of options documented here: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions by clicking **Show** next to Arguments for that call.

For example actions of adding cards to a board would be of type: `moveCardToBoard` so you would want to add that to the filter parameter.